# What injuries do cricketers face, and how do they recover from them?

Tags: cricket, injuries

This season of the IPL (Indian Premier League) saw many players getting injured and many new players were roped in as replacements. I wanted to know why is it that injuries are so common in modern-day cricket, the types of injuries, and the recovery process the cricketers undergo.